# TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable

Tags: python, feature-selection, dimensionality-reduction

I am trying to combine these feature selection methods. But there's an error here "TypeError: argument of type 'numpy.int64' is not iterable". How to fix this?

[image]

```
def get_true_false(selected_features, features):
    selected_t_f = []
    for feature in features:
        if feature in selected_features:
            selected_t_f.append(True)
        else:
            selected_t_f.append(False)
    return selected_t_f
```

```
features = sorted(df.drop('type', axis=1).columns)
df_selections = pd.DataFrame({'Feature': features,
                              'PCA': get_true_false(selected_features_pca, features),
                              'Information Gain': get_true_false(selected_features_ig, features),
                              'Lasso': get_true_false(selected_features_lasso, features)})
df_selections['Total'] = np.sum(df_selections, axis=1)
df_selections = df_selections.sort_values(['Total', 'Feature'], ascending=False)
df_selections.index = range(1, len(df_selections) + 1)
df_selections
```

Comment: The traceback error message appears to suggest that "selected_features_pca" is not an iterable (i.e. an array or list of things through which one might sift), but is instead an integer (numpy.int64). When you try "if feature in selected_features" - it appears that "selected_features" is not a "collection" IN which some "feature" may be found. Does that help? As I can't recreate your problem at my end, I can't offer more specific help than that. Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

For any reason your `selected_features` variable is an integer.

As mentioned in the error message its type is `numpy.int64`.
So you can't use `feature in selected_features`.

Because to be able to do that `selected_features` must be iterable, it must be a sequence e.g. a list.